# How can I recreate this two tables in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

In this case, the real text is irrelevant; the format and layout is what I'm interesed in. All my tries with it have seen deceptive.

I'm impatient to study your ideas!. Thanks in advance.

[image: Table 1, without colored background]

[image: Table 2, with alternate rows colored background]

Comment: Do the horizontal lines have to be red?

Comment: ...you could at least provide some standard table that includes the entries in the images you've uploaded... that would at least show that you've attempted *something*, rather than telling us you're "impatient for our ideas"!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As @Werner says, if you could provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)---that is, some code that you've tried---it would be really helpful, even if just to give us an idea of where we need to start in helping you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one try. You may adjust the colours though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=sf,labelfont={color=red,bf,sf},textfont=sf,labelsep=space}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}

%% \arrayrulecolor{magenta}  %%% uncomment this to have all rules in this color
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption[Some table]{This is my table}\label{tab:mytab}
    \begin{tabular}{*{3}{G}>{\textcolor{green!40!blue}\bgroup\arraybackslash}G<{\egroup}}
    \arrayrulecolor{magenta}\toprule
      \scshape Some text & \scshape Some text here & \scshape Some text & \multicolumn{1}{G}{\scshape
          And some more text here} \\\midrule
      Some text & Some text here & some text & and some more text here \\
      Some text & Some text here & some text & and some more text here \\
      Some text & Some text here & some text & and some more text here \\
      Some text & Some text here & some text & and some more text here \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

  \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \rowcolors{2}{}{gray!25}
    \caption[Some table]{This is my table}\label{tab:myothertab}
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{G}}\arrayrulecolor{magenta}\toprule
      \scshape Some text & \scshape Some text here & \scshape Some text & \scshape And some more text
           here \\\midrule
      Some text & Some text here & some text & and some more text here \\
      Some text & Some text here & some text & and some more text here \\
      Some text & Some text here & some text & and some more text here \\
      Some text & Some text here & some text & and some more text here \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answers, and --specially-- to Harish Kumar. Your example is valuable for me, for many reasons.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers, and --specially-- to Harish Kumar. Your example is valuable for me, for many reasons.
The problem, now, is the accents: whem I integrated the code in my own code, suddenly appear errors related to accents. 
I suppose the problem is collision with other packages I use.
I cannot include my package list cause I haven't sufficient privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code reproducing as faithfully as possible the first table of the OP. It requires  loading mainly `caption` and `floatrow` (for the position of the caption), plus `microtype`, `xpatch`and  `makecell`.

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

        \usepackage{springer}

        \usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar, textwidth = 15cm]{geometry}
        \usepackage[svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
        \usepackage{array, booktabs, colortbl}
        \usepackage{caption, floatrow}
        \usepackage{makecell}
        \usepackage[tracking]{microtype}
        \usepackage{xpatch}
        \xapptocmd{\toprule}{\addlinespace[-1pt]}{}{}
        \xpretocmd{\midrule}{\addlinespace[-3pt]}{}{}
        \xapptocmd{\midrule}{\addlinespace[5pt]}{}{}

        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
        \renewcommand{\lightrulewidth}{0.06em}

        \DeclareCaptionFormat{leftmargin}{\captionsetup{textfont={small, sf, md, up}, labelfont={small, sf, md, up}, labelsep=space, position = above, slc = off} \raggedright\textls*[150]{\MakeUppercase{#1 #2}}#3}%

        \floatsetup{captionskip = 4pt}%

        \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\SetTracking{encoding= *, shape= sc}{180}\color{black}\rmfamily\scshape}%
        \renewcommand{\theadalign}{tl}

        \begin{document}
        \setcounter{table}{3}

        \begin{table}[!h]
        \centering\arrayrulecolor{DeepPink3!50!DeepPink2}\captionsetup{format = leftmargin, font = {color ={DeepPink3!50!DeepPink2}} }
        \ttabbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Properties of everyday  -- or Galilean -- velocity.}}%
        {%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}*{3}{l} >{\color{SeaGreen2!45!Cyan4}\sffamily}l@{}}
        \toprule%
        \thead{Velocities\\can} &   \thead{Physical \\ properties}  &  \thead{Mathematical \\ name} & \thead{Definition}\\
        \midrule
        \addlinespace[0.25ex]
        Be distinguished  & distinguibility  & element of set  & Vol.  III,  page 242 \\
        Change gradually  & continuum & real vector space & \makecell[tl]{Page 77, Vol.  V,  \\ page 349} \\
        Point somewhere, direction & vector space,  dimensionality & Page 77 \\
        Be compared & measurability & metricity & Vol. V, page 340 \\
        Be added  & additivity & vector space  & Page 77 \\
        Have defined angles  &  direction & Euclidean vector space  & Page 77 \\
        Exceed any limit & infinity & unboundedness  & Vol.  III,  page 243 \\
        \addlinespace
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        }%
        \end{table}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sample. When I compiles it, appears an error: "springer.sty not found".
I don't know where I cant get this package.

Comment: @karloswitt: Oh yes! It's to use a rather confidential/unofficial font, once developped be Springer Verlag based on Adobe's Minion Pro and Myriad Pro. It was freely available at the time (2003). I took that one because it was more or less of the same style as your example. f you have Sebastian Schubert's `FontPro` package, you can use Adobe's fonts, after some work with fontinst, and you will obtain the same result. Otherwise you can use any pair of serif/sans serif matching fonts. Or you can use the opentype fonts directly with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (they come with Adobe Reader).

Comment: Many thanks. Your answers are very precise and, undoubtedly, useful to me.